# Dock disappearing on Mac

Tags: macos, dock

Why does the Dock disappear on my Mac? It pops back up when I put the cursor to the bottom of the screen but does not stay there permanently any longer.

Answer (score 6):

You've probably enabled Dock hiding. **You can toggle this by pressing ⌥⌘D**.

Alternatively, you can toggle it through System Preferences or by right-clicking the spacer between the apps and the stacks then turning Hiding off:

[image]

Comment: I did not enable hiding.. it just disappears

Comment: This worked perfectly for me. My dock settings in system preferences weren't set to hidden, but I must have hit ⌥⌘D without realizing it, because hitting ⌥⌘D again solved the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me, I don't remember turning Hiding On, but I must have done it inadvertently.  When I tried toggling it off, it fixes this problem.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.

Comment: @grgarside thanks for the comments and flag. I've edited this into an answer..